# U-SQL Python extension: How can I import a pyd file?

Tags: python, u-sql

I've looked at: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuredatalake/2017/03/10/using-custom-python-libraries-with-u-sql/

The blog post mentions that U-SQL's Python extension supports zipimport for custom modules. However, Python's zipimport does not support pyd files (e.g. compiled C-extensions).

I've tried modifying "UsqlPythonDeployPackage.zip\3.5.1\Lib\site-packages" by adding my modules (downloading the zip file, adding my module, uploading it again), but that didn't seem to work. It doesn't find my pyd-module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the compiled Python C-extension (pyd) to:

```
usqlext\assembly\python\UsqlPythonDeployPackage.zip\3.5.1\Lib\site-packages
```

seems to work just fine. However, I forgot to drop/creating the assembly again. Here's the code I used for that:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS master;
USE DATABASE master;

DROP ASSEMBLY IF EXISTS [ExtPython];
CREATE ASSEMBLY IF NOT EXISTS [ExtPython]
FROM @"/usqlext/assembly/python/ExtPy.dll"
WITH ADDITIONAL_FILES =
(
    @"/usqlext/assembly/python/ExtPy.pdb",
    @"/usqlext/assembly/python/UsqlPythonInvokePackage.zip",
    @"/usqlext/assembly/python/UsqlPythonDeployPackage.zip",
    @"/usqlext/assembly/python/version.python"
);
```